# How to insert NSArrys into NSDictonary by without changing the order

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am facing the problem to insert the data into dictionary. 
It is not saving data in the order I had given to it.
For this dictionary I am giving one keys array and one values array like this.

both arrItemDetails and arrItemNames are NSMutableArray instances

```
NSArray *detailsArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrItemDetails];

NSArray *namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrItemNames];

NSDictionary *dictWithItemNamesAndDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrItemDetails forKeys:arrItemNames];
```

But for my app I need to maintain order, so please help me regarding this.

I am giving outputs of namesArray (keys) and detailsArray (valuesarray) and after adding them how the dictionary is also kk

Printing description of arrItemDetails:

```
(
    hi,
    44,
    5,
    555,
    3
)
```

Printing description of arrItemNames:

```
(
    CardName,
    AccessNumber,
    AccessPause,
    Pin,
    Pause
)
```

Printing description of dictWithItemNamesAndDetails:

```
<CFBasicHash 0x6a90680 [0x274b380]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
 0 : <CFString 0xe3b4 [0x274b380]>{contents = "AccessNumber"} = <CFString 0x6d25970 [0x274b380]>{contents = "44"}
 1 : <CFString 0xe394 [0x274b380]>{contents = "Pin"} = <CFString 0x6d3cda0 [0x274b380]>{contents = "555"}
 3 : <CFString 0xe384 [0x274b380]>{contents = "Pause"} = <CFString 0x6d37080 [0x274b380]>{contents = "3"}
 5 : <CFString 0xe3a4 [0x274b380]>{contents = "AccessPause"} = <CFString 0x6d6c250 [0x274b380]>{contents = "5"}
 6 : <CFString 0xe3c4 [0x274b380]>{contents = "CardName"} = <CFString 0x6d56c70 [0x274b380]>{contents = "hi"}
}
```

I want to store data in needed order. This is my main concern.

Comment: Why do you need them to be in that order? Aren't you accessing them later by key name? Do they have to be in a certain order in a plist or something?

Comment: May be you need another array to store the order if you need. Since dictionary will not maintains the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary is not an ordered/indexed data structure. It is a key/value paired data structure. You can not guarantee the order of the keys. And after inserting new key/value the previous order might change. If you want to use dictionary, then you need to use keys to access the values, not any kind of index.

Comment: thanks Your suggestion is good and but i have to implement the things like I have to create a dictionary .Its keys and values are two arrays .Means my dictionary was created with those keys and values arrays. But once i am retrieving that dictionary the contents are changing with respect to each key value pair but the

Comment: order of keys and values are changing means the arrays indexes are changing

Answer (score 2):

If order matters to you, what you need is an array of dictionaries (with 'name' and 'detail' keys), not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to insert something into NSDictionary with a certain order. The two options to retrieve arrays of the content (allValues and allKeys) both note in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The order of the elements in the array is not defined

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @taskinoor, a dictionary isn't an ordered data structure.  Indeed, it should be irrelevant to your program what order the values are stored in the dictionary.  If you care about the order when you retrieve the values from the dictionary, either sort the `allKeys` array yourself or use one of the sorting methods, such as `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:` to get an array of the keys sorted by value.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` is an unordered collection. If you need order, you can either use @smorgan's advice, or try to implement your own `OrderedDictionary` class to do what you need. Matt Gallagher has a neat guide on that topic: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html.

Answer (score 0):

Still uncertain as to why the order matters, but I think your only option to to reorder things as you work with them. That is, if they're NSMutableArrays then you can "manually" move AccessNumber to position 0, etc., as you reference them.